# Get html elements (dynamically generated) with values using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

Is it possible using jQuery to get whole div content(dynamically generated elements) with values? For example, child element may be a div, span, select, or input?

I am trying to save whole div content(generated on fly) with values as .html file. I tried with one div which has form and input elements.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="inputs">
    <form class="mainForm">
        <div style="height: 100%;" id="div1">
                <label>Input1</label>
                <input type="text" id="input1" name="input1"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<input id="addform" type="button" value="Click to add Input"/>
<input id="getform" type="button" value="Click to get html"/>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input#addform").click(function(){
        $("div#inputs").append($('form.mainForm').clone().html());
    });

    $("input#getform").click(function(){
        alert($("div#inputs").clone().html());
    });
});
```

**FIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/UhJfn/

How to get whole `div#inputs` content with values (entered by user) On click of `Click to get html` button?

Help would be appreciated.

P.S: Here I used only one input in form. But in my real case, we do have select, span, image, etc.

Comment: wouldn't you just need values and types since you already know the html structure? A more real world demo would help

Comment: @charlietfl I just mentioned one div. But we have 10 divs with different html structure. I need to save whole html content as .html file.

Comment: seems to me that an array of objects with all the attributes/properties needed to replicate html output would make more sense than relying on browser to modify html and then copy that

Comment: @Oliver Have you checked out my solution.?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy How can we update values for select tag? And select tag options will be dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

You have to explicitly update the `value` attribute to achieve your need.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('keyup','input[type="text"]',function(){
        $(this).attr('value',$(this).val());
    });

    $("input#addform").click(function(){
        $("div#inputs").append($('form.mainForm').clone().html());
    });

    $("input#getform").click(function(){
        alert($("div#inputs").clone().html());
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UhJfn/3/)